# Can't save createdAt and updatedAt as datetime values nor backend neither frontend

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I'm trying to save datetime values in TodoForm but those values are not reflected in database. This is my todo model.

Todo.js

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose');
  const { Schema } = mongoose;

  const todoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    isDone: Boolean,
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
    },
   {timestamps: {createdAt: 'created_at' updatedAt: 'updated_at'}}
    );

 mongoose.model('todos', todoSchema);
```

Then Follows my todosController post route.

TodosController:

```
  app.post('/api/todos', async (req, res) => {
      const { name, description, isDone, createdAt, updatedAt} = req.body;

      const todo = new Todo({
            name,
            description,
            isDone,
            createdAt,
            updatedAt
       });

     try {
        let newTodo = await todo.save();
        res.status(201).send(newTodo);
       } catch (err) {
          if (err.name === 'MongoError') {
             res.status(409).send(err.message);
              }
        res.status(500).send(err);
           }
         });
```

That is from backend side. Code is next is from front end side.

TodoForm.jsx

```
   componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
      // Load Contact Asynchronously
      const { todo } = nextProps;
      if (todo._id !== this.props.todo._id) {
       // Initialize form only once
       this.props.initialize(todo);
       this.isUpdating = true;
      }
    };


   render() {
        const { handleSubmit, loading } = this.props;

       if (loading) {
         return <span>Loading...</span>;
      }

           return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field
            name='createdAt'
            component={DateTimePickerInput}
            dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'
            // dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm'
            // showTimeSelect
            timeFormat='HH:mm'
            placeholder=' todo createdAt...'
            label='CreatedAt'
          />
         <Field
            name='updatedAt'
            component={DateTimePickerInput}
            dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy'
            // dateFormat='dd-MM-yyyy H:mm'
            // showTimeSelect
            timeFormat='HH:mm'
            placeholder='todo UpdatedAt...'
            label='UpdatedAt'
           />

     <Link className='btn btn-light mr-2' to='/todos'>
            Cancel
           </Link>
          <button className='btn btn-primary mr-2' type='submit'>
            {this.isUpdating ? 'Updating' : 'Create'}
          </button>
         </form>
       );
    }
  }
```

I expect the output e.g when I complete todo form and click on submit button is "2020-09-18N14:00:30", reflected datetime value on database, but real output are empty createdAt and updatedAt datetime values.

What is wrong?

I'm calling my api from NewTodo.jsx

```
  state = {
      redirect: false
    };

   componentDidMount() {
     this.props.newTodo();
    }

   submit = todo => {
      return this.props
        .saveTodo(todo)
        .then(response => this.setState({ redirect: true }))
        .catch(err => {
          throw new SubmissionError(this.props.errors);
        });
    };
```

Comment: please add your handleSubmit funcion

Comment: const { handleSubmit, loading } = this.props; //there is

Comment: show me your handleSubmit code

Comment: I haven't got handleSubmit code. HandleSubmit code is imported from redux-form

Comment: from where are you calling your api??

Comment: I will edit publication and add NewTodo.jsx. I'm calling my api from NewTodo.jsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206254/discussion-between-francisco-arias-and-prakash-karena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : convert your date to string in your schema

schema

```
 createdAt: String,
 updatedAt: String
```

you can direclly store your data as you passed in your post request, if you want to convert it to required format then

Step 2 : use moment if you want to format your date in required format then install moment

```
npm install moment

const { name, description, isDone, createdAt, updatedAt} = req.body;
  const todo = new Todo({
        name,
        description,
        isDone,
        createdAt : moment(createdAt).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH.mm') , //change it as per your requirement 
        updatedAt : moment(updatedAt).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH.mm') ,
   });
```

Comment: I've got same issue.

Comment: let me know if you steel have any problem