# how to use react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm from frontend side. I'm using a DateTimePickerInput and I'm typing a datetime value to store it in database. This is my DateTimePickerInput

```
 import React from 'react';
 import Moment from 'moment';
 import momentLocaliser from 'react-widgets-moment';
 import DateTimePicker from 'react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker';

 const moment = require('moment');

 moment.locale('es');

 momentLocaliser(moment);

 const DateTimePickerInput = ({
   label,
   input,
   format,
   width,
   placeholder,
   onChange,
   selected,
   defaultValue,
   meta: { touched, error },
  }) => {
   return (
      <div className='form-group'>
       <label forname={input.name}>{label}</label> <br />
       <DateTimePicker
       {...input}
        placeholderText={placeholder}

          className='form-control'
          onChange={date => input.onChange(moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH.mm"))}
          selected={input.value ? moment(input.value, "DD-MM-YYYY HH.mm") : null}
          //onChange={input.onChange}
        />

       <div className='text-danger' style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}>
          {touched && error}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
 export default DateTimePickerInput;
```

I've got next issues:

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `String` supplied to `DateTimePickerInput`, expected instance of `Date`

//And

Uncaught TypeError: date[("get" + method)] is not a function

this problem is the continuation of another mentioned in this url:

[Can't save createdAt and updatedAt as datetime values nor backend neither frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817000/cant-save-createdat-and-updatedat-as-datetime-values-nor-backend-neither-fronte/59817377?noredirect=1#comment105773581_59817377)

previous problem talked about backend. This problem talks about frontend.

I don't know how to use DateTimePicker. What is wrong?

Comment: onChange={date => console.log('date' , date )  } you are getting your date in which format here ?

Comment: now It works fine when I save a date time value, but when I'm editting the date time picker value, I do click in datepicker value inside datetime picker component and I've got the next issues:                                                        Cannot read property 'map' of undefined                                                                 The above error occurred in the <MonthView> component                                         I guess it's an error from dependency in react-widgets/lib/DateTimePicker. Maybe I'm not controlling exception.

Comment: you can use react-datetime https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime it provide's all access to date,time

Comment: It works. Solved Problem.